# Flask-wtf Recaptcha always returns "the response parameter is missing"

Tags: python-3.x, flask, recaptcha, flask-wtforms

I am trying to implement Recaptcha 2 in a flask web form, however, my form always fails to validate when I have recaptcha enabled. To dig a little deeper I printed out the errors from recaptcha and I always get "the response parameter is missing". I have looked at the source code and it seems this error corresponds to "missing-input-response", however, I can see that the green tick appears when I click the button. Here are before and after images.

[image]

[image]

I have been searching the web for hours and can't find a reason why this is happening. Here is my flask code and my html.

flask:

```
import os
from flask import Flask, render_template
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from flask_wtf.recaptcha import RecaptchaField
from wtforms import StringField, SubmitField
from flask_wtf.file import FileField, FileRequired, FileAllowed
from wtforms.validators import DataRequired
from dotenv import load_dotenv

app = Flask(__name__)

# load env variables
load_dotenv(dotenv_path='app.env')
SECRET_KEY = os.getenv('CSRF_TOKEN')
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = SECRET_KEY
app.config['RECAPTCHA_PUBLIC_KEY'] = ''
app.config['RECAPTCHA_PRIVATE_KEY'] = ''

class InputForm(FlaskForm):
    email = StringField('Email-Adresse', validators=[DataRequired()])
    postcode = StringField('Postleitzahl', validators=[DataRequired()])
    upload = FileField('Angebotsdatei', validators=[FileRequired(), FileAllowed(['png', 'jpg', 'pdf'], "Invalid file format")])
    recaptcha = RecaptchaField()
    submit = SubmitField('Starten')

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index_2():
    email = None
    postcode = None
    upload = None
    form = InputForm()
    # validate form
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        email = form.email.data
        postcode = form.postcode.data
        upload = form.upload.data
        form.email.data = ''
        form.postcode.data = ''
        form.upload = ''
    return render_template(
        "index_2.html",
        email = email,
        postcode = postcode,
        upload = upload,
        form = form
        )

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True, host='127.0.0.1', port=5000)
```

html:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}

<div class="container containerform pt-3">
    <div class="container">
        {% if email %}
        <p class="text-center">Thanks for submitting to submitting the form!</p>
        {% else %}
        <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
            {{ form.email.label(
            class="form-label"
            ) }}
            {{ form.email(
            class="form-control"
            ) }}
            {{ form.postcode.label(
            class="form-label"
            ) }}
            {{ form.postcode(
            class="form-control"
            ) }}
            {{ form.upload.label(
            class="form-label"
            ) }}
            {{ form.upload(
            class="form-control"
            ) }}
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="recapture-box">
        {% for error in form.recaptcha.errors %}
            {{ error }}
        {% endfor %}
        {{ form.recaptcha }}
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="submit-button-form pb-4">
        {{ form.submit(
        class="btn btn-primary btn-form"
        ) }}
    </div>
    </form>

    {% endif %}
</div>


{% endblock %}
```

I would appreciate any pointers here.

UPDATE

I still haven't managed to fix the problem, however, the issue lies in validation. While I can click and run recaptcha, I am not able to store the validation from google, and hence my validation_on_submit() returns False.

Comment: Have you added the URL of your application to reCaptcha admin console? I mean either localhost or whatever else?

Comment: Yes I added 127.0.01

Comment: I see no requests on the reCaptcha admin console though…

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to review the explanation on [this](https://techmonger.github.io/5/python-flask-recaptcha/) web page.
You can use this instead of the `if form.validate_on_submit():`.

```
captcha_response = request.form['g-recaptcha-response']
if len(captcha_response) > 0:
```

Answer (score 0):

The [flask-wtforms](https://flask-wtf.readthedocs.io/en/0.15.x/form/#recaptcha) documentation states that:

> For your convenience, when testing your application, if app.testing is
> True, the recaptcha field will always be valid.

So you need to set `app.testing = True` while testing, else you have to set the RECAPTCHA_PUBLIC_KEY and RECAPTCHA_PRIVATE_KEY configuration variables with the respective public and private keys received from your [reCAPTCHA](https://console.cloud.google.com/security/recaptcha) registration.